# Is there any psion variant/ACF/etc that gets Grip of Iron?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, optimization, psionics, archetype

I have a character who would really like to have *grip of iron*, the 1st-level psychic warrior power. However, said character is a psion, specifically an egoist, not a psychic warrior, and doesn’t have a feat to spare for Expanded Knowledge.

Is there any variant, ACF, etc. that allows a psion to learn *grip of iron*? All 3.5e material (including 3.5e-legal 3e material) in Wizards of the Coast sources or *Dragon* or *Dungeon* magazines are acceptable. Said variant cannot touch the 1st-level bonus feat, as I am already using the variant shapeshifter egoist to get *minor change shape* instead of that bonus feat.